# Issues with displaying messagebox in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, messagebox

I have the following message box in c# on my asp.net page inside the btnSubmit_Click event.
It tends to popup sometimes and not popup sometimes. Any reasons as to why it is not consistent?

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    GetType(),
    "alert",
    "alert('An email has been sent to Customer Service');",
    true);
```

Comment: Have you verified the javascript is in the emitted page source? If so, can you check the status of script errors in your browser? What do they say?

Comment: not sure what you mean by that, Anthony.

Comment: 1) Check the conditions in your .NET code for when you are displaying the message. The conditions, on postback, etc. Then view the page HTML source and verify your start up script is there. 2) If you're using IE, check the status bar for a notification that there were script errors. If using another browswer such as Firefox, check the Error Console.

Comment: Using IE browser displays no error icons; Viewing source seems everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that this will depend on the text you are putting inside the `alert`. In the example you provided the text is hardcoded but I suppose that in your real application this text is dynamic and might contain characters that break javascript such as `'`. Try using [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see if there are some javascript errors when it doesn't work.

Comment: @user, being that client side javascript is volatile, there could be errors with your script *or with other scripts present on the page* that could lead to your alert window not appearing. Check the error information.

Answer (score 0):

Have You checked, if the `alert('An email has been sent to Customer Service');` line is in the HTML Source after you clicked the Button and the message did NOT appear?

If it isn't in the HTML, check:

1. with the Debugger if your
   codeblock is hit
2. are you maybe redirecting the response?

Answer (score 0):

try these popups instead
type java directly in the visualstudio GUI

On a button go to the "OnClientClick" property (its not into events*) over there type:

```
 return confirm('are you sure?')
```

it will put a dialog with cancel ok buttons transparent over current page if cancel is pressed no postback will ocure. However if you want only ok button type:

```
 alert ('i told you so')
```

The events like onclick work server side they execute your code, while OnClientClick runs in the browser side. the come most close to a basic dialog

as this codes is so small it should work unless they have really strange browser clients